# Gcloud Container Service - Docker ps -a command shows other user's containers

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I am trying out GCE for the first time and i have a laradock + Laravel Application. I setup a VM `n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory)` and added a small persistent disk. I `git clone` my repo and did a `docker-compose up` (After doing a few more settings like env variable etc.

Now when i do `docker ps -a` to see all the containers. I am seeing many containers. Most of them have random user's names!

The ones which are running are mine. Everything else i have no clue.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

What is going on! Isn't my VM a private one?

Answer (score 1):

Your VM is indeed a private one, what you call "random user names" are simply random names that docker generates to identify an image if you don't provide one yourself. Each time a container is run is given a random name unless you provide one yourself. They use a random adjective from a list + a name of a famous scientist or engineer [here you can see the code on Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go). They are there because they are easier to remember than an hexadecimal container ID for a human.

Also there is a funny Easter Egg on that code:

```
func GetRandomName(retry int) string {
begin:
    name := fmt.Sprintf("%s_%s", left[rand.Intn(len(left))], right[rand.Intn(len(right))])
    if name == "boring_wozniak" /* Steve Wozniak is not boring */ {
        goto begin
    }
```

Also, those containers have been generated by you. Every time you run docker-compose up you have been starting all the containers and then stopping them. Notice that the status shown is "Exited" for all of them. Also you can see an exit code to see if the process finished successfully. From the docker-compose CLI help:

```
The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.
```

If instead of `docker ps -a` you  run simply `docker ps` you'll notice that in only lists the containers that are running at this moment. The flag -a stands for *all* and lists everything you have run.

Answer (score 0):

That are not other user containers. Since you're using `docker ps -a` (-a) flag all containers are shown. Also containers that are not running anymore are shown, they're not deleted and you see them.

Comment: But whose are they? I didn't make these containers

Comment: @notANerdDev "docker-compose up"  does "docker run ..." for you. You could provide your docker-compose file for more details. The ourpoot is still wired... But i guess you have some problems in docker-compose file

Comment: I have used this docker-compose.yml in my local machine. It builds fine. And it does not create these containers. There is definitely something wrong. I've reported to Google Issue Trackers. Note how these containers have been started or stopped within the last few hours. These are not because of my actions. Other users must have performed their own docker run commands.

Comment: @notANerdDev which image you took for your machine? I mean which OS?

Comment: Container-Optimized OS 64-10176.7.0 dev

Comment: @notANerdDev aha. have  you added some cloud-init script that starts container automatically? How did you start your stuff first time?

Comment: Nope. Nothing at all.

Comment: @notANerdDev you have not tried to start your container  at all?